# Floating menus disturbing my floating content

Tags: html, css, css-float

In my HTML page I have a total of 3 menus :

- 1 on the left
- 1 on the right
- 1 in the middle above the content

The left and right menus are floating, and the middle content and menu have a margin equals to the width of the menus to center it.

This is working fine. However, when I insert some other floating content in my content block and I stop it with `clear: both;`, the next content I add is added below the side menu with the largest height.

Here is a simple fiddle that shows the issue : http://jsfiddle.net/Xy9Ry/

As you can see, the `other content` text is displayed below the left menu instead of being displayed just below the `floating content`.

What can I do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `.content`

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xy9Ry/2/)

[w3c Wiki article on Overflow](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/overflow)

`overflow: auto;` also works

Comment: Thank you this is working fine, I'll accept your answer as soon as I can