# My floating element disturbs other elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a problem with my brand new html & css sites : I want to have a  that opens when hovering on a floating element of itself. The problem is not on animation but on layout. When it's empty, it works well, but when I add content into the , it goes under the floating element. To solve this, I've tried different overflow values as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053254/floating-menus-disturbing-my-floating-content), but of course the part of the  whitch is "outside" of it got impacted.

(in this sample, the "menu" is already opened)

```css
section
{
 background-color: white;
 margin: 10px;
}
.scroll_aside{
 overflow-y: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.aside_left{
 width: 70%;
 height: 100%;
    display: block;
 background-color: gold;
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
}
.aside_left .cote{
 position: relative;
 top:0px;
 right: -80px;
 width: 80px;
 background-color: orange;
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-left:0;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="TEST2.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class='aside_left'><span class='cote' onclick="openjourney()">Floating on the right</span>
            <div class="scroll_aside">
                <section style='height: 400px'>Section 1</section>
                <section style='height: 800px'>Section 2</section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Another thing I've noticed is that when the content is thin enough, it goes to the top....
But what I want, is to have the content taking all the , so going at the top and with width=100%.
Is there a way to do that ?
Thank you in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of float use absolute position:

```css
section {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}

.scroll_aside {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.aside_left {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: gold;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.aside_left .cote {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: orange;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='aside_left'><span class='cote' onclick="openjourney()">Floating on the right</span>
  <div class="scroll_aside">
    <section style='height: 400px'>Section 1</section>
    <section style='height: 800px'>Section 2</section>
  </div>
</div>
```